# Ubuntu 22.04.1 settings gnome-control-center suddenly disappeared

Tags: settings

This happened today. it just disappeared and seem to have been be uninstalled while in past day no updates were made (update/upgrade.
To get it back : sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center

Comment: What is the question? Yo always may ask a question and then post the answer on this site if you think the information you can share is useful to other users.

Comment: I thought maybe I was going crazy, or had somehow accidentally deleted it (hard to imagine how). But I'm pretty sure this happened to me too. Here's a question: why/how did this happen?

Comment: It seems to have been useful for someones peace of mind.